# Jupyter notebook snap package not seeing / importing packages / modules

Tags: python, snap, python3, jupyter

The Jupyter notebook snap package is not seeing / importing packages / modules

I'm trying to convert a list to a vector numpy float32 list array

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and installed Jupyter from the Software center

Code used:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install numpy
import numpy as np
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [10, 20, 30, 40]
z = [100, 200, 300, 400]

xyz = (list(zip(x, y, z)))
xyz = np.float32(xyz)
type(xyz)
```

Output:

[image: python]

Answer (score 0):

My System looked and I had to reboot then it started to work

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install numpy
import numpy as np
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [10, 20, 30, 40]
z = [100, 200, 300, 400]

xyz = (list(zip(x, y, z)))
xyz = np.float32(xyz)
print(type(xyz))
print(xyz)
```

output:

```
    Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/rt/snap/jupyter/common/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.19.0)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[  1.  10. 100.]
 [  2.  20. 200.]
 [  3.  30. 300.]
 [  4.  40. 400.]]
```